# Java:Why is this not possible?

Tags: java

```
    String myName[] = {"Mouse","Laptop","Facebook","Logitech"};

    // print the first character
    System.out.println(myName.charAt(0));

    // print the second character
    System.out.println(myName.charAt(1));

    // print the last character
    int lastPos = myName.length() - 1;
    System.out.println(myName.charAt( lastPos ));
```

/*any one can explain to this noob? It's telling me to change to length, but that's not what I want. Basically what I want is to go through each character of string. */

Comment: Array types dont' have `charAt(int)` and `length()` methods.

Comment: myName is an array of strings, to make it a single string you have to choose which string first. ie `myName[0].charAt(0)` This is the first letter of the first word.

Comment: You need some form of a `loop` to go through all elements of an array.

Comment: Hmmm I got more information and learned more by reading these few posts , then I did from my teacher in last few weeks...
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `String` methods on an array. To access the characters in the strings, you need to first get one of the `String` objects sitting in that array. Doing `myName[0].charAt(0)` for example will give you the first character of the first `String` in the array. If your intention is to do something with each character in each string in the array, you should use a loop like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<myName.length; i++){
    for (int j=0; j< myName[i].length(); j++){
        myName[i].charAt(j);  // Do something with ths value, I am just getting it here.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized an array of string.Later if u want to access them you cannot directly use myName simply. Because its a container which has many memory locations in which data is stored. So by just using myName is not possible instead it should be followed by its index (ie, myName[i] pass 0,1,2.. in place of i). See the modification of ur program below. May be u can understand it.

```
public class ArrayDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String myName[] = {"Mouse","Laptop","Facebook","Logitech"};

        for(int i=0;i<=myName.length()-1;i++){
                // print the first character
        System.out.println(myName[i].charAt(0));


        // print the second character
        System.out.println(myName[i].charAt(1));

        // print the last character
        int lastPos = myName[0].length() - 1;
        System.out.println(myName[i].charAt(lastPos));
        }
}

}
```

Comment: we don't say "my dear friend" to someone we have never even communicated with before.  This kind of "effusive politeness" went out of style 50+ years ago.  These days, it just sounds ridiculous.  (As well as being literally false.)

Comment: It is a common mistake made by non-native English speakers. It might be because it's considered polite in the person's native tongue or just the way they were taught English, but that's a conversation for [SE English](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

**You have created an Array of Strings** where each element in that array is a "String". So, you can't use charAt to the array.

**charAt(index) by it's name - you can think (give me the character at position index)**.

So, first you need to go to the particular "String" and then say "give me the character at position 'x' ".

So, if you want to go to **"Facebook"**, then say hey "give me the element of the array at position 3 which is index 2" using:

```
myName[2];
```

store it in say variable str which needs to be a "String" :

```
String str = myName[2];
```

**Then, you can use** **charAt(x) on str** using :

```
for(int i =0 ; i<str.length() ; i++){
System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
}
```